# mbed tls NET and TIMING modules not available

Tags: arm, mbed, dtls, mbedtls

I have compiled mbedtls for a K64F board with ARM Mbed OS. I am trying to run the examples that come in the dtls_client.c and dtls_server.c. Initially, on compiling the client I got this error:

```
"The NET and TIMING modules are not available for mbed OS - please use the network and timing functions provided by mbed OS"
```

I found that this was related to having this two lines active in the config.h file.

```
    #define MBEDTLS_NET_C
    #define MBEDTLS_TIMING_C

I commented them and the check that requires the values:

#if !defined(MBEDTLS_SSL_CLI_C) || !defined(MBEDTLS_SSL_PROTO_DTLS) ||    \
    !defined(MBEDTLS_NET_C)  || !defined(MBEDTLS_TIMING_C) ||             \
    !defined(MBEDTLS_ENTROPY_C) || !defined(MBEDTLS_CTR_DRBG_C) ||        \
    !defined(MBEDTLS_X509_CRT_PARSE_C) || !defined(MBEDTLS_RSA_C) ||      \
    !defined(MBEDTLS_CERTS_C) || !defined(MBEDTLS_PEM_PARSE_C)
int main( void )
{
    mbedtls_printf( "MBEDTLS_SSL_CLI_C and/or MBEDTLS_SSL_PROTO_DTLS and/or "
            "MBEDTLS_NET_C and/or MBEDTLS_TIMING_C and/or "
            "MBEDTLS_ENTROPY_C and/or MBEDTLS_CTR_DRBG_C and/or "
            "MBEDTLS_X509_CRT_PARSE_C and/or MBEDTLS_RSA_C and/or "
            "MBEDTLS_CERTS_C and/or MBEDTLS_PEM_PARSE_C not defined.\n" );
    return( 0 );
}
```

Now I see that the compilation error I get is related to the redefinition of certain functions:

```
main.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x18): undefined reference to `mbedtls_net_init'
main.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0xce): undefined reference to `mbedtls_net_connect'
main.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x2fc): undefined reference to `mbedtls_net_recv_timeout'
main.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x300): undefined reference to `mbedtls_net_send'
main.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x304): undefined reference to `mbedtls_net_recv'
main.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x308): undefined reference to `mbedtls_timing_get_delay'
main.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x30c): undefined reference to `mbedtls_timing_set_delay'
main.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x35c): undefined reference to `mbedtls_net_free'
```

How can I define this calls to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered here: https://tls.mbed.org/discussions/platform-specific/compiling-mbeddtls-on-k64f:

> Hi Jordi,
>   `dtls_client.c` and `dtls_server.c` are sample applications that arrive as part of the mbed TLS git repository.
>   Note that mbed-OS arrives with its own mbed TLS feature directory. To test TLS feature, you can use the [TLS client app](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-tls/tree/master/tls-client) and modify it to fit DTLS protocol, and also for server. You can also look at this example for reference how to configure your dtls client and server.
>   I hope this helps
>   mbed TLS Team member
>   Ron